# Understanding forbidden selection rule $m_J=0$ to $m_J=0$ for $\Delta J=0$

Tags: angular-momentum, atomic-physics

I am seeking to gain a physical understanding of the specific single-photon selection rule which states that for $ΔJ=0$ i.e. ($J = J’$), transitions involving $m_J=0$ to $m_J’=0$ are forbidden.

Particular mention of this special instance can be found [here](http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/AtSpec/node17.html)

Mathematically, this can be shown by the fact that the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient with the corresponding $3j$ symbol being zero:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}J&1&J'\\0&0&0\end{array}\right) 
$$

Intuitively, one (albeit hand-waving) way I can think about this is that since the total angular momentum, J of the atom is unchanged, the direction (i.e. projection) of the angular momentum and therefore m_J needs to change.  Hence this selection rule.  Is this a valid way of thinking about this?  If this were the case though, then wouldn’t this result in the more restrictive selection rule that $ΔJ=0$, $Δm_J=0$ transitions should be forbidden rather than only the specific $m_J=0$ to $m_J’=0$ case?

Any help aiding in a physical understanding would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have same question with you. but I can not understand this sentence, "Intuitively, one (albeit hand-waving) way I can think about this is that since the total angular momentum, J of the atom is unchanged, the direction (i.e. projection) of the angular momentum and therefore m_J needs to change. "
Why "the direction (i.e. projection) of the angular momentum and therefore m_J needs to change."???

Comment: I am also eager for an answer to this question. I agree that your intuitive picture ("$m_J$ needs to change") would imply a more restrictive selection rule and therefore cannot explain this particular constraint.

Comment: The link in the question is dead. Please update, along with a proper reference.

Comment: Can you add a working reference?